# Selecting text between two words from word document using pywin32

Tags: python, vba, winapi, pywin32

than finding keywords and inserting text (from a list) under those keywords.
the problem is that the keywords appear in more than one place in the document and I want to insert the text under keywords that are in specific places.

I am using pywin32 to copy text from a table in a word document than paste it on under a specific keyword on the same document. I want to search for that keyword in a specific range/ selection that will be between two keywords, one of which will always be under a section break.

The code:

```
def getRange(d_add):
    word.Documents.Open(d_add)
    doc = word.ActiveDocument

    rng1 = doc.Range
    print(rng1)
    if rng1.Find.Execute(FindText= "Introduction") == True:
        rng2 = doc.Range(rng1.Start, doc.Range.Start)
        if rng2.Find.Execute(FindText = "Conclusion") == True:
            myRange = rng1(rng1.End, rng2.Start).Text
    print(myRange)
```

produces the following error:

```
if rng1.Find.Execute(FindText= "Introduction") == True:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Find'
```

But it exists in VBA (Find) why doesn't it work? do I need to import another module other than win32com ?

Comment: What is `word`? Please add all the code as specified in [\[SO\]: mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `word` is defined such as:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
word = Dispatch("Word.Application")
```

or something equivalent, the answer to your question on the error is you are missing parentheses after the word `Range`. If you replace `rng1 = doc.Range` by `rng1 = doc.Range()` you won't get this error anymore.

The rest of the code has some errors too. If I understand well the purpose of your code, then this code should work:

```
def getRange(d_add):
    from win32com.client import Dispatch # not the only possibility
    word = Dispatch("Word.Application")
    word.Documents.Open(d_add)
    doc = word.ActiveDocument

    rng1 = doc.Range() # Select all your doc
    print(rng1)
    if rng1.Find.Execute(FindText= "Introduction") == True:
        # Now rng1 == "Introduction" and you want to search in your original doc 
        # for the word "Conclusion" after the word "Introduction"
        # so you need to specified the start point of your selection for rng2
        # being after the end of rng1
        rng2 = doc.Range(Start = rng1.End) # no End as you look until the end of the doc
        if rng2.Find.Execute(FindText = "Conclusion") == True:
            # Now rng1 == "Introduction" and rng2 == "Conclusion"
            # To select the text between these two words in your original text,
            # you to specified the start and end position in your range
            # being respectively after the end of rng1 and before the start of rng2
            # Note: the +1 helps to not take into account the first element after "Introduction"
            # probably being a space or a new line in the doc
            myRange = doc.Range(Start = rng1.End + 1, End = rng2.Start)
            print(myRange) # if not indented as the line myRange, an error occurred  
                           # if one of the two words looked for are not found,
                           # myRange would not be defined then
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks you very much, but I used some other method of gaining the range, Do you know a lot about pywin32? because  I haven't found that much documentation

Comment: I don't know a lot and indeed I didn't find a lot of documentation about pywin32. I usually use the documentation of [VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/office-vba-reference) and try to transpose to python/pywin32.