# How do I check if a word is in a word document with python's pywin32?

Tags: python, vba, pywin32

I have found the following VBA code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.found.

```
With Selection.Find 
.ClearFormatting 
.Font.Bold = True 
.Execute FindText:="Hello", Format:=True, Forward:=True 
If .Found = True Then 
.Parent.Expand Unit:=wdParagraph 
.Parent.Copy 
End If 
End With
```

However I am not sure how to write this in python.

Would anyone be able to help me convert the code to python?

Comment: I think you will find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088417/selecting-text-between-two-words-from-word-document-using-pywin32

Comment: Whilst not a conversion of your code, here is a link to extracting text from a word document using Python.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228106/how-to-extract-text-from-an-existing-docx-file-using-python-docx searching for a specific string should be very straightforward afterwards.

Comment: @SnowGroomer used that method and worked perfectly